# Replace values in multiple columns by values of another column on condition

Tags: r

I have a data frame similar to this:

```
> var1<-c("01","01","01","02","02","02","03","03","03","04","04","04")
> var2<-c("0","4","6","8","3","2","5","5","7","7","8","9")
> var3<-c("07","41","60","81","38","22","51","53","71","72","84","97")
> var4<-c("107","241","360","181","238","222","351","453","171","372","684","197")
> df<-data.frame(var1,var2,var3,var4)
> df
   var1 var2 var3 var4
1    01    0   07  107
2    01    4   41  241
3    01    6   60  360
4    02    8   81  181
5    02    3   38  238
6    02    2   22  222
7    03    5   51  351
8    03    5   53  453
9    03    7   71  171
10   04    7   72  372
11   04    8   84  684
12   04    9   97  197
```

I want to replace all values of the variables `var2,var3,var4` with `"0"` that exist where var1 is `02` and/or `03`. The digit number also needs to be the same so that `df` looks like this:

```
   var1 var2 var3 var4
1    01    0   07  107
2    01    4   41  241
3    01    6   60  360
4    02    0   00  000
5    02    0   00  000
6    02    0   00  000
7    03    0   00  000
8    03    0   00  000
9    03    0   00  000
10   04    7   72  372
11   04    8   84  684
12   04    9   97  197
```

Now, I also need to be sure the command will be executed, even if `var1` would not contain `02` or `03`.
Basically something like if `var1` contains `01` or `02` set the corresponding values in `var2`,`var3` and `var4` to `0` according to the number of digits in `var2`,`var3` and `var4` (e.g. `97` will be `00` and `197` will be `000`) and if not, do nothing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use `mutate` and `case_when` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(var2 = case_when(var1 %in% c('02','03') ~ '0',
                          TRUE ~ as.character(var2)),
         var3 = case_when(var1 %in% c('02','03') ~ '00',
                          TRUE ~ as.character(var3)),
         var4 = case_when(var1 %in% c('02','03') ~ '000',
                          TRUE ~ as.character(var4)))
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to automatically make as many zeros as there are digits in the variable you can use something like this

```
# define a function
val_to_zero <- function(con, val){ifelse(con, paste0(rep(0,unique(nchar(as.character(val)))), collapse=""),val)}
# define the condition
con <- df$var1 %in% c("01", "02")
# choose which columns to change
vars <- names(df)[2:4]
# apply the function to columns    
df[ , vars] <- do.call("cbind.data.frame", lapply(df[, vars],function(var_i){val_to_zero(con, var_i)}))
# done
df
```

For this function you do not need to tell by hand how many zeros to use for what column. So if `var5` is `c("292992", ...)` it still works.

Comment: Even with just two conditions, you may want to consider `df$var1 %in% c("01", "02")` rather than `df$var1 == "01" | df$var1 == "y"`. It's less typing and extends more easily if there are more cases.

Comment: I find the solution with dplyr from @camnesia a bit more straightforward. But also thanks for this suggestion. Maybe other users prefer this option.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea where we can do this dynamically for any number of columns, for any number of digits. The trick is to make sure you have character variables (instead of factors) and use `sprintf` based on the maximum `nchar` of each column, i.e.

```
#Convert to character (IF they are factors)
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
#Convert values to 0 as per your condition
df[df$var1 %in% c('02', '03'), -1] <- 0
#Add leading 0s to bring to same format as original
df[-1] <- mapply(function(x, y){i1 <- sprintf(paste0('%0', x, 's'), y); gsub(' ', '0', i1)}, 
                               sapply(df[-1], function(i)max(nchar(i))), df[-1])
```

which gives,

> ```
>    var1 var2 var3 var4
> 1    01    0   07  107
> 2    01    4   41  241
> 3    01    6   60  360
> 4    02    0   00  000
> 5    02    0   00  000
> 6    02    0   00  000
> 7    03    0   00  000
> 8    03    0   00  000
> 9    03    0   00  000
> 10   04    7   72  372
> 11   04    8   84  684
> 12   04    9   97  197
> ```

Comment: Interesting suggestion. I can´t apply this to my original data (there are more columns that shouldn´t be converted to 0 but of course, you could not know from my question), but I think this can be very useful in future. Thanks!

Comment: You can exclude unwanted columns. For example, in this case I exclude the first column (that's why I have the `-1`, i.e. `df[-1]`). If you replace the `-1` above with the index of columns you want to exclude, it should work just fine