# How to replace a value by function in R using mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

How do I change a value in a column for a specific condition by a calculation?
So I want to divide by 7 for some of the values in a particular column. It is not possible for me to share data or codes. But my question is almost exactly like this previous question [Replace values in multiple columns by values of another column on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60671984/replace-values-in-multiple-columns-by-values-of-another-column-on-condition)
someone answered the question (named camnesia) with this code:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(var2 = case_when(var1 %in% c('02','03') ~ '0',
                          TRUE ~ as.character(var2)),
         var3 = case_when(var1 %in% c('02','03') ~ '00',
                          TRUE ~ as.character(var3)),
         var4 = case_when(var1 %in% c('02','03') ~ '000',
                          TRUE ~ as.character(var4)))
```

I tried to run the code for my data like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(var1 = case_when(var2 %in% c('A') ~ var1/7,
                          TRUE ~ as.character(var1)))
```

I want to change the values in var1 that belongs to group 'A' (groups are defined in var2 column), by dividing the values with 7? How do I add that calculation to the above code? Because it does not work like this for me.

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: When using `%>%`, `.` is a stand-in for the entire dataset. So `./7` is attempting to divide all of `df` by 7. You need to instead specify `var1 / 7`. And also ensure consistent output types as per @JanZ’s answer.

Comment: Also note it’s a bit simpler to use `ifelse()` or `dplyr::if_else()` instead of `case_when()` when you have just two conditions.

Comment: thanks for answering! :) How can I use if else in my case instead of case_when? I'm really new at R, so I don't know how I should replace case_when at all -.-'
I have tried to specify by saying var1 / 7, that did not work for me

Comment: It will be hard to help you more without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/17303805). I understand you can't share your specific data, so please provide some example made-up data that demonstrates the same problem. Also specify what you mean by "it does not work" -- are you getting an error? What is it? Or are the results just not what you expect? What are they? You can [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: I’m sorry for that. I should have made up some data. I appreciate you telling me this as I’m very new to R and also new at stackoverflow.
I will edit by question as soon as I can and add some made up data. 
But if you still want to know, the “it does not work” means that I’m getting this error 
“Error in ‘mutate()’: problem while computing ‘the whole code in my question’ caused by error in ‘var1/7’: non-numeric argument to binary operator”. 
Thanks a lot for trying to help!

Comment: It’s okay!! Thank you for being so open to feedback. That error implies `var1` isn’t a number. You can check by running `class(df$var1)`. Have you tried @JanZ’s second code block, which includes `as.character(as.double(var1)/7)`?

Comment: Thanks a lot! it Worked! :D I tried @JanZ at first and it made an error. I might have typed something wrong at the beginning. But thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have consistent type for column var1. In your code you mix numerical with text.
You should encompass the division in `as.character()`
This should work, assuming `var1` was numerical:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(var1 = case_when(var2 %in% c('A') ~ as.character(var1/7),
                          TRUE ~ as.character(var1)))
```

If `var1` was character at start, then:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(var1 = case_when(var2 %in% c('A') ~ as.character(as.double(var1)/7),
                          TRUE ~ as.character(var1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately that did not work for me either. It says that there is something wrong the calculation ./7. I tried to remove the dot and run (/7). But that don't work either. var1 is numerical

Comment: Could you please provide sample data?

Comment: My bad, replace the dot `.` by `var1`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not allowed to share my data. I appreciate your help! But that didn't work for me either (replacing the dot by var1)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked for me by running the as.double function :D I might have typed something wrong at start.